# How to rotate annotation label in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts and I have an issue with rotating the annotation label. I want to have the ability to rotate it to certain degrees for better data presentation. Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
    annotations: [{
        labels: [{
            point: {
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0,
                x: 10,
                y: 15
            },
            text: 'Annotation Label',
            style: {
                // Here I tried to rotate the label
                transform: 'rotate(90deg)'
            }
        }]
    }],
    ...
});
```

This code doesn't seem to work, the labels are still displayed horizontally. I've looked through the Highcharts API documentation but didn't find any property specifically for rotating annotation labels.

Could someone please guide me on how to rotate the annotation labels in Highcharts? Are there any specific methods or properties that I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rotation as a property for annotations, but technically `annotations.label` is the same as `chart.renderer.label`, so you can rotate it in the same way.

For example:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.annotations[0].labels[0].attr({
          rotation: 90
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/udoxstwm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement